# Paginating with query string parameters that include arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, pagination

Does it make any difference in terms of SEO (google crawling all pages) and user experience if my paginated query string contains arrays as follows:

```
search?foo[]=a&foo[]=b&foo[]=c&foo[]=d&bar[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3&page=1
```

Or should I be shortening the query string by formating the arrays into a comma separated list as follows:

```
search?foo=a,b,c,d&bar=1,2,3&page=1
```

In the first example the length of the query string could potentialy end up huge if all parameters are selected but it does make for simpler coding i.e. i dont need to keep imploding/exploding paramters in the back end. Is there a limit to the length of a query string and does is make a difference to a google crawl?

Any tips or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say anything if it matters for SEO, but from a user perspective I would think the second method looks much cleaner. The technical effort of implementing it isn't that huge either, you could simply use something like array_walk for applying it to multiple parameters.

There are limits for GET-Parameters, they depend on the Client Browser and also Server Config, i.e. IE limits it to 2083, you find the details here:
[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)